# Xpath dealing with SPAN and SUP

Tags: python, html, xpath

I'm trying to webscrape holiday table on that website file:///C:/Users/alexa/AppData/Local/Temp/tmptz9muzp9.html
i got headers and first and third columns but the 2nd columns looks like :

```
<td>
<span>1<span>
<sup>er <sup>
<span> ...
```

when i use my xpath : `span_xpath = tree.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/article/div/table/tbody/tr/td/span/text()')`

it returns a list where the sup 1"er" is not here and add a additional line with an undesired code

```
   ['1',
 '\xa0janvier (lundi)',
 '1',
 '\xa0janvier (mardi)',
 '2 avril',
 '1',
 '\xa0mai (mardi)',
 '1',
 '\xa0mai (mercredi)',
 '10 mai (jeudi)',
 '21 mai',
 '23 juin (samedi)',
 '23 juin (dimanche)',
 '15 août (mercredi)',
 '1',
 '\xa0novembre (jeudi)',
 '1',
 '\xa0novembre (vendredi)',
 '25 décembre (mardi)',
 '25 décembre (mercredi)',
 '26 décembre (mercredi)']
```

i would like the whole path with span and sup.

Comment: Just open the html file in the browser and right click on it to inspect it. Then right click on the element in the source and go to _Copy_>_Xpath.

Comment: That's not help me, if I choose xpath with sup I got only the superior term er, if I choose xpath span I got the rest but I want both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the question and OP's comment, He should be able to modify the XPath query slightly to accept both `span` and `sup` elements:

```
q = "//*[@id="main"]/article/div/table/tbody/tr/td/*[self::span|self::sup]/text()"
span_xpath = tree.xpath(q)
```